# How can I use malloc from a function?

Tags: c, arrays, int, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to understand how malloc works. I did a program searches for the largest element in a one dimensional array int.

This is the code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void largest_element(int *nbr)
{
    int i;
    int n;
    int m;

    i = 1;

    nbr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(nbr) + 8);

    while (i < 8)
    {
        if (*nbr < *(nbr + i))
            *nbr = *(nbr + i);
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d ", *nbr);
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int tab[8] = {11, 2, 4, 5, 9, 7, 8, 1};
    int n = sizeof(tab)/sizeof(int);

    i = 0;

    largest_element(&tab[8]);

    return(0);
}
```

The program works without malloc but how can I make it work with malloc? What did I do wrong and why does my code only give me garbage numbers?

Comment: There's no reason to call `malloc` in this code.  You're reading from an array, not modifying it.  Also, you should be passing in `tab`, not `&tab[8]`.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how malloc works and how to resolve this exercise using malloc.

Comment: Then please provide the definition of the problem too.

Comment: It prints out garbage values or 0 instead of the right number.

Comment: The definition of the problem, dude. In English.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc), 1) the return type is `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer.  The cast just clutters the code, making understanding, debugging, maintenance much more difficult.  2) Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this line: `largest_element(&tab[8]);` is passing the address of the first element past the end of the tab[] array. Probably not what you want. Suggest: `largest_element(tab);`   In C, arrays are indexed starting with 0 and continuing through number of elements in array-1.

Comment: the posted code is using a 'magic' number.  I.E. 8  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  Strongly suggest giving that 'magic' number a meaningful name via a `#define` or `enum` statement, Then using that meaningful name throughout the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are lost with pointers and arrays so you can not understand malloc properly (no offense, everyone who is learning C do the same mistake).

Let's take your main function. When you run:

```
int tab[8] = {11, 2, 4, 5, 9, 7, 8, 1};
```

You staticly allocate an array of 8 integers and you fill it with your numbers.

The dynamic equivalent would be:

```
int* tab = malloc(sizeof(int) * 8);
tab[0] = 11;
tab[1] = 2;
/// Etc...
tab[7] = 1;
```

First thing: the first element of an array has the index 0. So in your `largest_element` function, `i` should be initialized at 0 instead of 1.

The reason is, when you deal with array, you deal with pointers. In your case, `tab` is a pointer to the first element of the array. So, when you do `tab[3]`, you get the forth element of your array.

Second thing: when you do:

```
largest_element(&tab[8]);
```

You send to your function the eighth element after the begining of your array. The problem is: you do not own this memory area! You own the memory only until tab[7].

If you want to send the complete array to your function, just use:

```
largest_element(tab);
```

Now, let's talk about your `largest_element` function.

1. You do not need to call malloc here since the memory is already allocated
2. When you do `*nbr = *(nbr + i);` you change the value of the first element of your array. I think you wanted to do `m = *(nbr + i);` isn't it.
3. Why do you not use the `nbr[i]` instead of `*(nbr + i)`?

A correct implementation of this function would be something like (not tested):

```
void largest_element(int *nbr)
{
    int i = 0;
    int max = 0;

    while (i < 8)
    {
        if (max < nbr[i])
            max = nbr[i];
        i++;
    }

    printf("%d ", m);
}
```

A last thing, using malloc involve using the function [free](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm) to release the memory when you do not need it anymore.

Comment: FYI - don't cast the result of an `Xalloc()`

Comment: I completely agree with and your are right. I did the same function without malloc and it worked. Its just that i want to know for sure how to use malloc. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**What did I do wrong and why does my code only give me garbage numbers??**

In `largest_element(int *nbr)` `nbr` points to the array `tab` in `main` (at least if you call it like this: `largest_element(tab);` instead of like this `largest_element(&tab[8]);`

Then you call `nbr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(nbr) + 8);` now `nbr` points to some allocated memory which has not been initialized and which contains garbage values. Now if you read from that memory it's normal that you get garbage values.

You simply don't need `malloc` for this problem, just as you don't need floating point math or file system related functions for this problem.